# Why CFormModel::validate needs in tableName?

Tags: php, yii, yii-components

I have `ChangeEmailForm` extending `CFormModel`:

```
<?php

/**
 * LoginForm class.
 * LoginForm is the data structure for keeping
 * user login form data. It is used by the 'login' action of 'SiteController'.
 */
class ChangeEmailForm extends CFormModel
{
    public $newemail;
    public $password;

    /**
     * Declares the validation rules.
     * The rules state that username and password are required,
     * and password needs to be authenticated.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            array('newemail, password', 'required'),
            array('newemail', 'email'),
            array('newemail', 'unique', 'attributeName' => 'User.email'),
            array('password', 'authenticate')
        );
    }

    /**
     * Declares attribute labels.
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'newemail' => 'Новый Email-адрес',
            'password' => 'Пароль учетной записи'
        );
    }

    /**
     * Authenticates the password.
     * This is the 'authenticate' validator as declared in rules().
     */
    public function authenticate($attribute, $params)
    {
        if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
            $user = User::model()->findByAttributes(array(
                'password' => $this->password,
                'id' => Yii::app()->user->id
            ));
            if ($user === null)
                $this->addError('password', 'Неверный пароль учетной записи.');
        }
    }
}
```

Also I have the following action in `ProfileController`:

```
public function actionSettings()
{
    $profile = $this->loadModel(Yii::app()->user->id);
    $model = new ChangeEmailForm;

    // if it is ajax validation request
    if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='change-email-form')
    {
      echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
      Yii::app()->end();
    }

    // collect user input data
    if(isset($_POST['ChangeEmailForm']))
    {
      $model->attributes=$_POST['ChangeEmailForm'];
                        // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
                        if($model->validate()) {
        $this->redirect('/');
      }

    }

    $this->render('settings',array(
      'model'=>$model,
      'profile'=>$profile,
    ));
}
```

And view:

```
<?php
/* @var $this ProfileController */
/* @var $model ChangeEmailForm */
/* @var $profile User */
/* @var $form CActiveForm */

$this->breadcrumbs=array(
    'Учетная запись',
);
?>

<h1>Настройки учетной записи</h1>

<h2>Смена email-адреса</h2>
<div class="form-register">

    <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'change-email-form',
        'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
    )); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-label"><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'newemail', array('class'=>'label1')); ?></div>
        <div class="col col-input"><?php echo $form->textField($model,'newemail',array('size'=>32,'maxlength'=>64, 'class'=>'input1')); ?></div>
        <div class="col col-error"><?php echo $form->error($model,'newemail'); ?></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-label"><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'password', array('class'=>'label1')); ?></div>
        <div class="col col-input"><?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password',array('size'=>32,'maxlength'=>128, 'class'=>'input1')); ?></div>
        <div class="col col-error"><?php echo $form->error($model,'password'); ?></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row buttons">
        <div class="col col-label"></div>
        <div class="col col-input"><?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Сменить пароль', array('class'=>'submit1')); ?></div>
    </div>

    <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->
```

Problem: after submitting the form my application throws an exception: **ChangeEmailForm and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "tableName".**

Question: why does `CFormModel` throw this exception? Why does everything work in example of `LoginForm` in `SiteController`?

**P.S.** Sorry, but I'am a beginner in Yii.

Comment: Are you running `actionSettings()` I'm assuming?

Comment: Yes, actionSettings()

Comment: It would be better to post your question related code snippets right here at SO but not to share them from off-site servers. Somebody facing the same problem later will not find them if the links become broken.

Comment: Okey, but a had problems with post code here.

Comment: If you have some problems with formatting the code you can use any [online PHP formatter](http://www.phpformatter.com), then copy formatted code to the clipboard, paste here and indent it by `Ctrl+K`.

Comment: @Ezze Thank you. I didn't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the following `rules()` method in your `ChangeEmailForm`:

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('newemail, password', 'required'),
        array('newemail', 'email'),
        array('newemail', 'unique', 'attributeName'=>'User.email'),
        array('password', 'authenticate'),
    );
}
```

As one can see [unique](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/#hh21) validator used for `newemail` attribute can be applied only to `CActiveRecord` linked with some database table through [tableName()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#tableName-detail) but not to `CFormModel`:

> Validates that the attribute value is unique in the corresponding database table.

Instead you can [write a custom validation method](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/168/create-your-own-validation-rule/#hh0) for your form model to test whether entered email already exists in database table represented by `User` model.